# bad Auth::attempt in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have some problem with Auth::attempt. When i write good Login with bad password attempt login into website anyway with wrong user. Why it dont work ?

Method:

```
public function postLogin(LoginRequest $request) {      
    if (Auth::attempt(["name" => $request["name"], "password" => $request["password"]])) {
        return Redirect::route("home");
    } else {
        return Redirect::route("home");
    }
}
```

LoginRequest

```
class LoginRequest extends Request {

public function rules() {
    return [
        "name" => "required|exists:users",
        "password" => "required",
    ];
}

public function messages(){
    return [
        "name.required" => "Login is empty.",
        "password.required" => "Password is empty.",
        "name.exists" => "User not found.",
    ];
}
```

}

I know i redirect to same view, but view have 2 options for auth and !auth, but I see auth page when I login with good login and bad password, other options works. What did I wrong ?

Regards

edit:
view

```
<form action={{ route("login") }} method="post">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" /><br />
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" /><br />
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" /><br />
                Remember me! <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="remember_me" value=""/><br />
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Zaloguj" />
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

the password column is named "password" ? and is hashed?

you can see the doc for more information.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: i saw request data with dd, with good name + password it work, but not with good name + bad password

Comment: @gargi258 The code you've posted does the same thing for good/bad logins.

Comment: attempt dont check login passed or not ?
and I know, but home view have 2 options for !auth and auth

Comment: @gargi258 you configure config/auth file? with table name?,

and the password column and name column exists in the table?

Comment: mmm the password column should be large varchar because hashed is very long, maybe cut the hashed password.

Comment: bcrypt the password and save in  your database